# How to concatenate a variable text value with a fixed string in customtextview

Tags: java, android

I can manage to generate a custom TextView with the help of stack overflow, now I am curious to concatenate a variable text with fixed string. I have done this but it doesn't help.

```
import android.content.Context;
```

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class CustomTextViewTest extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

```
public CustomTextViewTest(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomTextViewTest(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomTextViewTest(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    super.setText(text, type);

    // here set color according to text
    if (text.toString().contains("Available")) {
        this.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    }
    if(text.toString().contains("Not Available")){
        this.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)); }

    if(text.toString().startsWith("0")||text.toString().startsWith("1")||text.toString().startsWith("2")||
text.toString().startsWith("3")||text.toString().startsWith("4")||text.toString().startsWith("5")||
            text.toString().startsWith("6")||text.toString().startsWith("7")||text.toString().startsWith("8")
            ||text.toString().startsWith("9")){
        setText(text.toString()+" $");  //this line show something unexpected


    }
}}
```

How to get rid of this?

Comment: Can you include the full relevant code?  What is `setText()` ?

Comment: Are you taking numeric input and want to put dollar sign at the end?

Comment: I have retrieved the value of a specific child of my real time firebase database and want to put the dollar sign to the right of the value if and only if the value is numeric.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have added full code of CustomTextViewtest.java file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a numeric value and add a dollar sign at the end, first define a format string resource as follows:

```
<string name="amount">%1$s $</string>
```

and then later provide the numeric value as follows:

```
double amount = "100.00"
...
amountTextView.setText(context.getString(R.string.amount, amount));
```